# ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized. I am stuck

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2012

Using,

Visual Studio 2012
C#
WPF
SQL Server Compact 4.0

I have my code here. When i submit my categoryName it shows

> "ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized"

Plz help me. I am trying to add a data from textbox to database.

```
    private void btnCategoryAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCeCommand com = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO Category_Master(CategoryName) VALUES(@CategoryName)");
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CategoryName", tbCategoryName.Text);

        try
        {
            int affectedRows = com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (affectedRows > 0)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Insert Success !", System.Windows.Forms.Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                tbCategoryName.Text = "";
            }
            else
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Insert Failed !", System.Windows.Forms.Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, System.Windows.Forms.Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        con.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed to pass connection instance to `SqlCeCommand`

```
SqlCeCommand com = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO Category_Master(CategoryName) VALUES(@CategoryName)",con);
```

Comment: Hi . thanks. i assume it worked. but another error shows up. column cannot contain null value. is that because my database is empty. how to overcome that.  I also have a column named categoryID. which is notnull, primary and unique.

Comment: Ys. It worked. I forgot to add auto increment for the unique ID.

Answer (score 0):

Assign Connection Property

```
com.Connection = con
```